# How to get the text type?

Tags: haskell

I've the following code

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Lib where

import Data.Text (Text)

class DoSomething a where
  something :: a -> IO ()

instance DoSomething String where
  something _ = putStrLn "String"


instance DoSomething Text where
  something _ = putStrLn "Text"
```

And in REPL, I tried to get an instance of `Text` type as the following:

```
:t something ("hello" :: Text)
```

and the compiler complains:

```
<interactive>:1:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘something’, namely ‘("hello" :: Text)’
      In the expression: something ("hello" :: Text)
```

By default, it will take the `String` type :

```
:t something "hello"
something "hello" :: IO ()
```

How to get `Text` type instead of `String` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing problematic with your code. Doing something like this itself would result in such an error:

```
λ> import Data.Text
λ> let t = "hello world" :: Text

<interactive>:11:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "hello world" :: Text
      In an equation for ‘t’: t = "hello world" :: Text
```

But you can do that fine with `String`:

```
λ> let t = "hello world" :: String
```

Note that even though your file has `OverloadedString` extension in it, it won't be loaded when you load that file in the repl. You can see the currently loaded extensions like this:

```
λ> :show language
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
```

You can use the `OverloadedStrings` extension to annotate it to `Text` or even `ByteString`.

```
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> :show language
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
  -XOverloadedStrings
λ> let t = "hello" :: Text
λ> import Data.ByteString
λ> let t = "hello" :: ByteString
```

With the above extension set in repl, your code will work:

```
λ> :t something ("hello" :: Text) 
something ("hello" :: Text) :: IO ()
λ> something ("hello" :: Text) 
Text
```

The OverloadedStrings extension adds support for overloaded strings. You can find more detabils about it [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings). Short explanation of it: By definining your type to be an instance of `IsString` typeclass, you can denote it via String literal:

```
import GHC.Exts (IsString(..))

data MyFancyText =
  MyFancyText String
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance IsString MyFancyText where
  fromString str = MyFancyText str
```

And then in REPL:

```
λ> let xs = "hello" :: MyFancyText
λ> :t xs
xs :: MyFancyText
```

Comment: Generally, instead of `:set -XWhatever`, it's nicer to use `:seti -XWhatever` – that only sets `-XWhatever` for the interactive mode.  With `:set`, GHCi will interpret all future `:load`ed files with `-XWhatever`, leading to strange errors when you try to compile those files and discover that `-XWhatever` isn't enabled for them.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to enable `OverloadedStrings` in ghci itself. Run it like this:

`ghci -XOverloadedStrings file.hs`

and then it should work:

```
> :t something ("hello" :: Text) 
something ("hello" :: Text) :: IO ()
```

Comment: You can also enable it within GHCi by typing `:set -XOverloadedStrings`