# Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out, how to build `JSON` in `Haskell` with the following example:

```
module Main where


import GHC.Exts
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as T

val :: Value
val = Object $ fromList [
  ("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3]),
  ("boolean", Bool True) ]

main :: IO ()
main = T.putStrLn . T.decodeUtf8 . encode $ val
```

When I tried to compile, the compiler complains:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
      Expected type: Item Object
        Actual type: ([Char], Value)
    • In the expression: ("boolean", Bool True)
      In the first argument of ‘fromList’, namely
        ‘[("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, ....]),
          ("boolean", Bool True)]’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘fromList
           [("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, ....]),
            ("boolean", Bool True)]’
   |
12 |   ("boolean", Bool True) ]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Note that you can use the script feature of Stack to easily reproduce things: https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/stack-script#script-interpreter

That will be useful for others to reproduce your problems exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you get is about wrong string representation. Haskell has many of them, e.g. `ByteString` (strict or lazy), `Text` (strict or lazy), `String` (alias for `[Char]`). The last one is the default and also the one you should avoid most of the time.

Aeson library uses the `Text` as string representation. You can fix your code using `T.pack` before the string (to convert it to Text), like this:

```
val :: Value
val =
  Object $
  fromList
    [ (T.pack "numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3])
    , (T.pack "boolean", Bool True)
    ]
```

Or you can just enable `OverloadedStrings` extension. When it's on then Haskell compiler will try to figure out which string representation it should use. Just put `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` at the top of your file and it should work.

Answer (score 11):

You need to put `OverloadedStrings` extension on top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T
import GHC.Exts

val :: Value
val =
  Object $
  fromList
    [ ("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3])
    , ("boolean", Bool True)
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = T.putStrLn . T.decodeUtf8 . encode $ val
```

And on executing them:

```
$ stack fuse.hs
{"boolean":true,"numbers":[1,2,3]}
```

To understand the reasons on why that makes it work, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54824657/1651941).